# Is it possible to use USB OTG to SSH into a raspberry pi running on ubuntu server 20.04.3USB OTG

Tags: networking, server, usb, ssh

I'm trying to ssh into a Raspberry pi running on ubuntu 20.04.3.
I found an article on how to enable USB OTG for RaspberryOS: https://dev.webonomic.nl/4-ways-to-connect-your-raspberry-pi-4-to-the-internet/comment-page-1?unapproved=51493&moderation-hash=8dff1f2e9a2e04f800f70e955615a791#comment-51493
But I could not find similar articles for Ubuntu.
I made the same settings as in this article, and now when I connect raspberrypi to my computer, I see it in the list of devices, but I still cannot connect to it via SSH.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. Please provide all error messages, your Ubuntu version and all other details, so that one can find an adequate answer.

Comment: Version of ubuntu As well as the essence of everything is described in the question. There are simply no error messages. Nothing to connect to.